# Grails plugin site version syntax

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

On the Grails Plugin Site (http://www.grails.org/plugins/), every plugin lists the versions of Grails that it is compatible with; something like `Grails version : 1.2 > *`.

Does this mean that the plugin is compatible with all versions of Grails starting with 1.2 or up to 1.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it means that version is supported for mentioned and above versions. But do read that whether the plugin is deprecated or not. For that you need to go to plugin and then see the details at the bottom.

For example, Cloud Foundary is depreciated but it is still listed on Grails plugin page. 
http://www.grails.org/plugin/cloud-foundry